# Branch on equality test in Agda? (basic)

Tags: agda

A very basic question, but as an Agda beginner I'm stumped.

I just want to check if two terms are equal and return different things based on the different cases. I could write my own equality tester, but how do I do this using equiv (or what is the proper way to do it)?

This is a minimal example:

```
import Data.Nat
import Relation.Binary
myeqtest : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
myeqtest x y = if x Data.Nat.≟ y then true else false
```

Error message:
    .Relation.Nullary.Core.Dec (x .Relation.Binary.Core.Dummy.≡ y) !=<
    Bool of type Set
    when checking that the expression x Data.Nat.≟ y has type Bool

I actually want to do something more complicated of course (I know that the above is redundant in several ways), but the point is that x \?= y is not of type Bool, it is of type Set, and I don't know how to turn that Set into a Bool. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boring imports:

```
open import Relation.Nullary
open import Relation.Nullary.Decidable
open import Relation.Binary.Core
open import Data.Bool hiding (_≟_)
open import Data.Nat
```

Now let's ask Agda, what she thinks:

```
myeqtest : ℕ -> ℕ -> Bool
myeqtest x y = {!x ≟ y!}
```

C-C C-d in the hole gives `Dec (x ≡ y)`. `Dec` is about decidable propositions and defined in the `Relation.Nullary.Core` module:

```
data Dec {p} (P : Set p) : Set p where
  yes : ( p :   P) → Dec P
  no  : (¬p : ¬ P) → Dec P
```

I.e. there always exists a proof of either `P` or `¬ P`, where `¬` means "not". This is just a handmade law of excluded middle for some proposition. In our case there always exists a proof, that one number is either equal or non-equal to another.

So `Dec` has two contructors: `yes` and `no`, and you can use them in pattern-matching:

```
myeqtest : ℕ -> ℕ -> Bool
myeqtest x y with x ≟ y
... | yes _ = true
... | no  _ = false
```

There is a function in the `Relation.Nullary.Decidable` module, that turns a `Dec` into a `Bool`:

```
⌊_⌋ : ∀ {p} {P : Set p} → Dec P → Bool
⌊ yes _ ⌋ = true
⌊ no  _ ⌋ = false
```

So you can define `myeqtest` as

```
myeqtest : ℕ -> ℕ -> Bool
myeqtest x y = if ⌊ x ≟ y ⌋ then true else false
```

or simply

```
myeqtest : ℕ -> ℕ -> Bool
myeqtest x y = ⌊ x ≟ y ⌋
```

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense. Understanding where the connection to Dec comes in is really helpful especially, and then explaining what \lfloor and \rfloor are and how they work.