# Given a function in Agda, some argument, and a new value, how to generate new function where the result for this argument will be the new value

Tags: function-definition, agda, formal-verification, formal-semantics

Let's suppose that I have some `f : A -> B`, `a : A`, `b : B`. I want new function, that is almost a copy of `f`, but it should produce `b` for an argument `a`.

I was trying something like this.

```
replace_f : ∀ {A B} (f : A -> B) (a : A) (b : B)
    -> (A -> B)
replace_f f a b = \ { a -> b ; attr -> f attr }
```

But the `a` in the lambda definition is not the same as `a` that I am trying to replace.
Agda just considers it as a variable.

P. S.
I have also tried to use *Decideable* and prop equality in `replace_f f a b var = if ⌊ Dec (var ≡ a) ⌋ then b else (f var)` .
However, it errors with `Set _p_391 !=< Dec _P_386 when checking that the expression Dec (var ≡ a) has type Dec _P_386`

P. P. S.
If you want to reproduce the `Decidable` solution, use these imports

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality using (_≡_)
open import Relation.Nullary
open import Relation.Nullary.Decidable
open import Relation.Binary.Core
open import Data.Bool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the question given by my supervisor.

He suggests to implement and provide the equality test for the `A` type.

Overall, the `replace_f` will look like this:

```
replace_f : ∀ {A B} (decide : (x : A) -> (y : A) -> Dec (x ≡ y)) (f : A -> B ) (a : A) (b : B ) -> (A -> B )
replace_f decide f a b var = if ⌊ decide var a ⌋ then b else (f var)
```

*where decide is an actual implementation for comparison*

Actually, you could derive Eq clause automatically in Agda, see [Haskell Deriving Mechanism for Agda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209339/haskell-deriving-mechanism-for-agda)

Comment: Also, worth to check [Branch on equality test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306619/branch-on-equality-test-in-agda-basic)